# Spliting ArrayList into several ArrayLists based on variable

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to split an ArrayList containing primitive data types, String and ArrayLists to several ArrayLists based on a variable in this ArrayList.

I have my ArrayList `purchaseOrderList` with "brand" of type String among many others. I want to split this ArrayList into as many new ArrayLists as I have different brands. I keep ending up in an infinite loop no matter how I do it.

```
ArrayList<Brand> brandList = new ArrayList<Brand>();

brandList.add(new Brand(purchaseOrderList.get(0).getBrand()));
for (int i = 0; i < brandList.size(); i++) {
    for (Item item : purchaseOrderList) {
        if (brandList.get(i).getBrand().equals(item.getBrand())) {
            brandList.get(i).setItemList(item); //Add the items from the purchaseOrderList
        } else {
            brandList.add(new Brand(item.getBrand()));
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: use a [`Map<Brand,List<Item>>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) or a [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: Also, in your example above there is only one `Brand` in the `List`.

Comment: Is it not possible to do without using a map?

Comment: Are you afraid of maps?

Comment: I am working with GWT and think it would be easier to just use an ArrayList for what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of problem you should probably use a map :

```
Map<Brand, ArrayList<Item>> map = new HashMap<Brand, ArrayList<Item>>();


for(Item item : purchaseOrderList){
  if(map.get(item.getBrand()) == null)
    map.put(item.getBrand(), new ArrayList<Item>());
  else 
    map.get(item.getBrand()).add(item);
}
```

Comment: Thx. Easily implemented. Now I hope this will work fine with my GWT project.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop because you want to loop through all the elements of an array but in the same time you add new elements.

you should use: `int arraySize = brandList.size();` and use it's value in the first for, like this: `for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)`

This way you will traverse all the elements that are at the beginning in brandList array,
I guess that's what you want to do.